# How to find wifi speed in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, wifi

I have to develop an application which will be useful for finding the wifi speed. Based that wifi speed I have to change the position of wifi router. This app main purpose is to decide wifi router position in a room. But how to find speed of the wifi signal? How to find the speed of wifi internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by pinging a remote server repeatedly and see if the response time changes. Frankly I think the differences will likely be very minute but either way this is how you can can do it using AFNetworking.

```
startTime = CACurrentMediaTime(); //This will start the clock.

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

 double elapsedTime = (CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime); //in case of success you calculate the elapsed time

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

[I am adding this great tutorial on how to use AFNetworking.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks a lot mikael. I will try this once.

Comment: The method you have suggested is not working because control is not going to the elapsedTime statement. And also whenever i check the baseurl it is showing as null.

Comment: Does it go the failure block?

Comment: Clever answer. I will try it twice.

Comment: No Mikael It's not going. It's coming out.

Comment: You need to go through the tutorial I added i the answer because ou are doing something wrong. If the program neither goes to success or failure it's most likely that the block is not called.